# Send emails via PowerShell using Office365 account

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, sendmail

I want to send out emails using PowerShell's cmdlet `Send-MailMessage`, however we operate with Office365 and an infrastructure engineer has suggested to connect to Exchange with PowerShell, the user needs admin rights, which understandably, they do not want to grant. I thought this was excessive and wanted to see if there were any work arounds which allowed me to send emails through PowerShell using a standard email account

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) or EWS, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.